# Default field value from related custom record

Tags: netsuite

We have a custom tab created for item revision where the users enter item revision and the related data. The requirement is to get the active revision number from there and update the header field called ‘Current Revision’  on the item, this is another custom field. I have tried defaulting on the field setup but it does not give me an option to go through this custom record for the item and pick the value of revision where inactive is ‘No’. In the screenshot below, the highlighted field ‘Current Revision should show a value of ‘2’ as that is the only active revision.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6e74.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Creating Custom Fields with Values Derived from Summary Search Results](https://system.na0.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_3746191995.html&whence=) in the online help.

It shows you how to use the results of a summary saved search to set the default value for a custom field.

With this, you can edit your Current Revision field to use the saved search to calculate the value when an item record is viewed.

[image: Saved Search to set default value for custom field]

Comment: Thanks Mike for your inputs, I have used this feature before and it works fine when used with non custom records (I used it to count number of bills associated with a PO). However, this time when I have to derive the results from the custom record, the saved search does not show the custom record details, which is causing the issue. The issue is with saved search itself, I am afraid. Regards